# Is there a way to add 6502 Assembly to Google Code Prettify?

Tags: javascript, prettify, 6502

I have blog that is using Google Code Prettify.  My blog has a lot of 6502 Assembly Language code and I would like to add the instructions and directives.

I was hoping someone out there has learned how to add custom languages.  Or better yet, knows of a 6502 CSS file they could share?

Comment: MOS Technology actually.  MOS was made up of former Motorola employees but who cares right?

Comment: In fact you are lucky with that. The instructions have strict 3 letter mnemonics and they are less then 255. So you can even process them by javascript, reading from array, aha! instruction, document write, aha! parameter , document write etc....(with different style classes resulting with a hopefully beautiful output)

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of using an automated highlighting script though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Google Code Prettify, but I use Alex Gorbatchev's `SyntaxHighlighter` stylesheet in my 6502-based blogs on Blogger.

SyntaxHighlighter is [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

A quickstart guide for it is [here](http://abhinandanmk.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/how-to-format-source-code-for-blogger.html).

An example of its use for 6502 on one of my blogs is [here](http://vicpp.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/in-which-we-push-stack-around_13.html).